# BeagleBone Blue, rcpy module cannot be found (robotics cape library for python)

Tags: python, bash, module, beagleboneblack, robotics

I have written code for serial communication in PySerial, and am not having trouble with the PySerial library. However the rcpy library, which was downloaded the same way, goes unrecognized.

When run from bash:

```
python

>>> import serial

>>> import rcpy

Traceback (most recent call last):

    File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: no module named rcpy
```

When I try to run my code, the error is slightly different, telling me that 
Traceback (most recent call last):

```
File "/var/lib/cloud9/pyIMU.py", line 8, in <module>
import rcpy 
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/rcpy/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
from rcpy._rcpy import initialize, cleanup, get_state
ImportError: No module named _rcpy
```

I apologize for the terrible formatting, this is my first question.
Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Please go through https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. how did you install rcpy? Have you checked whether the Python environment is the same for both executions?

Comment: @darthsidous I followed the download instructions on this website: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/rcpy/0.3.5         I know that the PySerial is somewhat universal for python, and rcpy is meant specifically for the BeagleBone

Answer (score 0):

From the code block you wrote, I can assume that you are running in python-2.x, not python-3.x.

From the website(https://pypi.python.org/pypi/rcpy/0.3.5) you commented, it says that the library only supports Python 3,

so try,

```
$ python3
>>> import serial
>>> import rcpy
```

it will work if you installed it correctly using pip3